# Calling recycle() from finalize() crashes app with native crash

Tags: android, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, finalizer, android-memory

in order to confront with bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488 - (outOfMemoryError) which happens in android versions < 3.0 I'm trying to create a wrapper object that calls recycle() from its finalize(). That way I know for sure that this bitmap got recycled.

PS - I know that I can't trust the GB and finalizer for call finalize() on every object.

This is my code:

```
public class SmartBitmap extends Object {

private Bitmap bitmap;

public SmartBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            Log.d("SmartBitmap", "inside finalize");
    try {
        recycle();
    } finally {
        super.finalize();
    }

}

public void recycle() {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        bitmap.recycle(); //SYGDEV heap dmalloc error
        bitmap = null;
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}

public int getRowBytes() {
    if (bitmap != null)
        return bitmap.getRowBytes();

    return 0;
}

public void compress(CompressFormat compressFormat, int compressQuality, OutputStream out) {
    if (bitmap != null)
        bitmap.compress(compressFormat, compressQuality, out);
}

public int getHeight() {
    if (bitmap != null)
        return bitmap.getHeight();
    return 0;
}

public void copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer) {
    if (bitmap != null)
        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
}

public int getWidth() {
    if (bitmap != null)
        return bitmap.getWidth();

    return 0;
}

public Config getConfig() {
    if (bitmap != null)
        return bitmap.getConfig();
    return null;
}

public void setPixels(int[] argb, int i, int smallerSideLength, int j, int k, int smallerSideLength2, int smallerSideLength3) {
    if (bitmap != null)
        bitmap.setPixels(argb, i, smallerSideLength, j, k, smallerSideLength2, smallerSideLength3);

}

public void getPixels(int[] argb, int i, int smallerSideLength, int widthOffset, int heightOffset, int smallerSideLength2,
        int smallerSideLength3) {
    if (bitmap != null)
        bitmap.getPixels(argb, i, smallerSideLength, widthOffset, heightOffset, smallerSideLength2, smallerSideLength3);

}
```

}

But I keep getting native libraries crash on - bitmap.recycle();" //SYGDEV heap dmalloc error" and I don't have a clue why.

The log crash is:

```
07-25 00:58:50.444: D/SmartBitmap(9226): inside finalize
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 *** ***     *** *** ***
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119): Build fingerprint: 'SEMC/ST18a_1264-
0344/ST18a:2.3.4/4.0.2.A.0.62/wf_v3w:user/release-keys'
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119): pid: 9226, tid: 9227  >>> com.iprog<<<

07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr    0000000c
 07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  r0 6fd46470  r1 00439540  r2 00311da8  r3 00311d70
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  r4 00000000  r5 00000038  r6 00000038  r7 00000007
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  r8 100ffac8  r9 2d10efa0  10 2d10ef8c  fp 6caa4d38
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  ip 00000000  sp 100ffa78  lr 6fd10f30  pc 6fd13482   cpsr 80000030
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d0  643a64696f72646e  d1  6472656767756265
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d2  00000000000000ac  d3  000000000000002a
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d16 0000000700000000  d17 3ff0000000000000
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d18 42eccefa43de3400  d19 3fbc71c71c71c71c
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d20 4008000000000000  d21 3fd99a27ad32ddf5
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d22 3fd24998d6307188  d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
07-25 00:58:50.544: I/DEBUG(119):  scr 80000012
07-25 00:58:50.564: I/DEBUG(119):          #00  pc 00013482  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 00:58:50.564: I/DEBUG(119):          #01  pc 000145b6  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 00:58:50.574: W/kernel(130): [83323.416961] MtpIoctl:NoFreeBuffer()
07-25 00:58:50.574: W/kernel(130): [83323.416992] MtpIoctl:NoFreeBuffer()`
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.